# Gerar e fazer download de arquivo pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pechkin

Existe alguma configuração especifica pra gerar arquivo pdf no servidor ?
O Problema é que localmente em meu projeto local funciona perfeitamente e quando subo para o servidor o arquivo não é gerado, a página fica processando eternamente até atingir o timeout, o trecho de código é esse:

```
protected string GerarPDF(string html)
    {
        //Nome arquivo
        string nome = "Laudo_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", "_").Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_") + ".pdf";
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Laudos"), nome);

        try
        {
            var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());

            var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                .SetLoadImages(true)
                                .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                .SetAllowLocalContent(true), html);

            using (FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path))
            {
                file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
            }

            //Return the PDF file to download
            Response.Clear();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=" + nome + ", size={0}", pdf.Length));
            Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);

            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return nome;
        }
        catch
        {
            nome = string.Empty;
            return nome;
        }


    }
```

Implementei essa solução porém ocorre erro de conversão de  tipo de dados:

```
cannot implicity convert type
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este é o jeito **muito** errado de fazer. Nada garante que você está de fato manipulando a requisição com isso.

Há duas formas de você resolver isso corretamente:

1. Fazendo `GerarPDF` devolver um `byte[]`;
2. Fazer `GerarPDF` devolver um `FileAction`. Neste caso, `GerarPDF` seria uma `Action` do seu *Controller*.

Na primeira forma, fica assim:

```
protected byte[] GerarPDF(string html)
{
    //Retire isso aqui
    // string nome = "Laudo_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", "_").Replace("/", "_").Replace(":", "_") + ".pdf";
    // var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/Laudos"), nome);

    try
    {
        var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());

        var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                            .SetLoadImages(true)
                            .SetPrintBackground(true)
                            .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                            .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                            .SetAllowLocalContent(true), html);

        using (MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
        }

        return pdf.ToArray();
    }
    catch
    {
        nome = string.Empty;
        return nome;
    }
}
```

E o *Controller*:

```
    public ActionResult GerarLaudo()
    {
        // Coloque aqui a lógica pra gerar o HTML.
        byte[] arquivo = GerarPDF(html);
        return File(arquivo, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Laudo.pdf");
    }
```

O segundo método é a mesma coisa, só que você não vai separar em uma função chamada `GerarPDF`. Vai chamar o Pechkin e devolver o arquivo, tudo dentro da mesma `Action`.

Comment: olá Cigano dá erro de conversão de tipos, eu editei a pergunta e adicionei   o erro

Comment: Ops, errei. Veja agora.

Comment: Blz! Funciona rodando o meu projeto local, mas depois que publico e subo pro servidor não gera o pdf e não faz o download.

Comment: Mas dá algum erro? Ou nada acontece?

Comment: Não acontece nada.

Comment: Aí acho que é uma questão de debug. Não sei o que pode ser.

Comment: Ok obrigado, a situação é difícil porquê durante o debug em meu note funciona corretamente mas depois que o site é publicado não funciona, daí então eu não se é necessário alguma configuração no IIS além das dlls do Pechkin para poder gerar o pdf.

Comment: Depende de onde você publica. Se for na Azure em Web Site não vai funcionar. É o mesmo problema do Rotativa.

Comment: Funciona corretamente, porém o PDF gera mais de uma página e quando faço o download a página não é **numerada**, esse é um comportamento normal quando é gerado o PDF pelo **pechkin** ?

Comment: Eu acho que sim. Mas como o pechkin é um envelope do wkhtmltopdf, deve ter alguma opção pra definir a numeração das páginas pelo próprio pechkin.